# how to see the type of roads in Openstreetmap ROAD_CLASSES?

Tags: julia, openstreetmap

Based on the [OSMX.jl](https://docs.juliahub.com/OpenStreetMapX/3fbUy/0.1.13/reference/#OpenStreetMapX.ROAD_CLASSES) package and [OSM documentation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Highways) it seems Road classes carries information used for routing and plotting. I also read this page about [buses](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Buses)

But my question is having a map.osm file, how is it possible to find out all the nodes an links associated to public transits like buses, subways via OSMX.jl package automatically? and how to plot that?

Comment: OSMX does not support public transit lines. As far as I remember availability of such data in *.osm files is also limited (depending on city). When modelling public transport I have been using external data sources and mapping it onto an OSMX map. If course it would be possible to extend the library to read more data.

Comment: @Przemyslaw Szufel yes, Ive read the OSMX documentation and did not find anything to use. But OSM itself seems to have the information inside .osm file. Am I getting it right? 
 https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Buses

Comment: Is there any way to replicate that plotting automatically inside osmx.jl?

Comment: 1. It has information about public transport stops and routes. As far as I know there are no timetables so this information is insufficient for route planning (eg. in Warsaw we have bus lines that operate only during the night). 2. The plotting in OpenStreetMapXPlot.jl is very easy to extend - so if you want to add a functionality it is not a big deal.

Comment: @Przemyslaw Szufel actually the timetables is not of great importance to my problem, I just need to have stops and routes(edges) as a list and also be able to plot them.

Comment: In fact the plotting is the hardest one for me so far (working with OSMX.jl) when I want to inatall Pycall it shows various kind of error and incompatibility. I had all the dependencies installed but it doesn't work at all. Specially command starting by `pyimport`

Comment: OpenStreetMapXPlots works both with PyPlot and Plots.jl and you can actually use it to generate plots with Plots.jl via GR.jl backend